# Empty request data from java curl request

Tags: java, curl

Right now i need find method to send curl request from java.

I copy little API (for test) and work with java, but i find some problem.
When i do request from java, api doesnt see request data
(when i send curl from terminal, all works correctly)

Can someone help? Or sudgest another method to send curl from java

Python api

```
 from flask import request
  import flask
  import json


  app = flask.Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
  def create_task():
     print(request.data)
     print("test")
     return request.data

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, port = 5000)
```

Sending curl

```
   Process process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -X POST \\\n" +
                "  http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks \\\n" +
                "  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \\\n" +
                "  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \\\n" +
                "  -H 'Postman-Token: 28ab11c5-735f-4607-b6a1-fa0c32468006' \\\n" +
                "  -d '{\n" +
                "'\\''test'\\'':213\n" +
                "}'" );

    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(process.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("TEST");
```

Comment: Why is there many `\n` ?

Comment: Replace \\\n with \n.

Comment: If you are wroking in window's install choclaty and then curl package then you no need to write code like this or you can use postman.